# iOS 6 and iOS 7 UIButton label vertical align

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

There is a problem when i try to align uibutton textlabel.
on ios6 it's in center, but on ios7 it's about 4pixels lower.

Button class

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont seBoldUserFontOfSize:13.0]];

        _numberLabel = [[IBMSmallDescriptionTextLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.5, 0, 18, 18)];
        [self addSubview:_numberLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In custom header:

```
- (void)createButtons
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        IBMStageButton *button = [[IBMStageButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18.0 + (60.0 * i), 1.0, 18.0, 18.0)];
        [button.numberLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i+1]];
        [self addSubview:button]; // self frame W320 H23
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't encounter this problem yet(the translated label). I have actually, but it usually was the font issue. Make sure the problem is in the label itself before setting insets. In case the font is the problem, you can fix it using font tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this. I use:

```
if (iOS_7_or_later) {
    [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 0, 0, 0)];
}
```

The iOS_7_or_later is just a macro i use:

```
#define iOS_7_or_later SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")

#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```